# How to set start time and end time for coupon in Shopping Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, sales, coupon-codes, time

Currently, with Magento Shopping cart price rules, we can only set Start Date and End Date. How to set start time and end time along with date? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to use this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/time-dependent-shopping-cart-price-rules.html